# anchor tag links movig upward in interner explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, anchor

Why the anchor tag pointer showing upward outside the area of the button and ending in the middle of the button in internet explorer 
Any hint ????

[image]

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Could you add your HTML and CSS and the versions of Internet Explorer you are concerned with.

Comment: the problem is solved now . i have used an image cursor when i changed the cursor to default the problum is overcome.

Comment: now how i can fix the image height of the cursor.